# ClientClosedError: The client is closed in Node.js

Tags: node.js, redis

Node.js v19.7.0

I am confused with content of this artical[Introduction to Redis + Node.js](https://codeburst.io/introduction-to-redis-node-js-demo-f3326dd43c0f)
first exampe it given:

```
var redis = require('redis');
var client = redis.createClient();
client.on('error', function(err){
  console.log('Something went wrong ', err)
});
client.set('my test key', 'my test value', redis.print);
client.get('my test key', function(error, result) {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log('GET result ->', result)
});
```

I run this, and get an error:

```
/node_modules/@redis/client/dist/lib/client/index.js:477
        return Promise.reject(new errors_1.ClientClosedError());
                              ^
ClientClosedError: The client is closed
```

I checked the document of redis and found same question in stackoverflow, I changed the codes and add `await client.connect();`, it works, and I can use `redis-cli get 'my test key'` in terminal and get `my test value`.

my code:

```js
var redis = require('redis');
var client = redis.createClient();
const main = async () => {
  await client.connect();
  client.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log('Something went wrong ', err)
  });
  client.set('my test key', 'my test value', redis.print);
  client.get('my test key', function (error, result) {
    if (error) throw error;
    console.log('GET result ->', result)
  });

//   await client.quit();
}
main();
```

Does the artical is wrong? But I check this Youtube video [Redis Tutorial](https://youtu.be/uJb4HjtvcIE) from fullstack codecademy. It don't have `await client.connect();`.
I am confused about this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The article was correct in 2017. The video is equally as old. While I have merely scanned both—they mostly certainly are not using a [current version](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis/v/4.6.4) of Node Redis. Node Redis 4.x was released about two years ago, well after the video and article were published.

Node Redis 4.x introduced a lot of breaking changes. Most notably, it added desperately needed support for Promises and made all functions that invoke Redis commands camel-cased instead of lowercase.

There are lots of other changes too. You can read all about them in the [README](https://github.com/redis/node-redis) for Node Redis.

If you want to follow this article and video content, you'll need to use [Node Redis 3.x](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis/v/3.1.2) instead. But I would recommend against this as the code is rather dated in both examples—using callbacks and [CommonJS](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) instead of async/await and [ESM](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html).